# User role authorization with Scala-Play frameork

Tags: scala, spring-boot, playframework, jwt

I am new to Play framework and Scala. I know Json Web Tokens and concepts of authorization. I have done a Spring Boot app that does user role authorization with JWT. Basically, I put my custom key value pair while creating the JWT and it has something like this "authorizations":[role_employee, role_user]

When a request comes, I intercept it, parse the token, and create a spring security context and use the annotation on the spring controller method and the authorization works perfectly. I tried finding this concept in Play framework, most examples are talking about how to intercept the call and verify the validity of the token, but no one is talking about how to make sure the authorization is also correct. Basically, by merely verifying that token is fine, how do I create a binding that for a particular controller to be allowed to execute, what roles are permitted?

Comment: can you use this play plugin do that . https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful framework for authorization in the Play environment is the **Deadbolt**

https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2

You can also find simple authorization parts in the other frameworks. For example, I often use **Pac4J** for Play. It has authentification and simple authorization parts:

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j

Comment: Is there a good blog whihc has end to end depiction where a JWT is issued and then we use deadbolt for authorization?
Can a combination of JWT libraries(to generate jwt, validate) with deadbolt solve this in play framework for me?

Comment: I do not know such blog (or article)